# Removing trailing decimals from a .ToString("c") formatted number

Tags: c#, localization, currency

Basically I am formatting numbers like so

```
price.ToString("c")
```

The result is $615.00 in english and 615,00 $ in french.

My desired result, however, is $615 and 615 $, respectively.   How can I attain this, while still taking advantage of .nets localization handling?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you don't mind rounding...

```
price.ToString("c0")
```